# How can I authenticate SSP users in company website?

Tags: customer-portal, customer-community

Scenario:

We are going to create a content website for our users (contacts of accounts)

We want/need to secure this site with a username and password.

We currently have the SSP (Self Service Portal) of SF (Pre-communities) that we can use.

How can I embed/authenticate SF contacts/SSP users in the new Help-Content site?

Answer (score 0):

No, Self Service Portal users are not supported on Communities or Sites.